# Angular 4 directive is displaying undefined for @input values

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, angular2-directives

I'm new with angular directive so I had created a directive as follows:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[bonusCard]"
})
export class BonusCard {
  @Input() bonus: string;
  @Input() amount: string;
  @Input() isSeleted: string;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef){
    el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.getTemplate()
  }

  getTemplate(){
    return ''+
      '<div>'+
        '<div class="bonus">'+this.bonus+'</div>'+
        '<div class="amount">'+this.amount+'</div>'+
        '<div class="radio '+(this.isSeleted?'is_seleted':'')+'"></div>'+
      '</div>' +
      '';
  }
}
```

I'm using this directive in template as follows:

```
  <div class="column col-3" *ngFor="let b of bonusJson;let i = index" bonusCard [bonus]="b.bonus" [amount]="b.amount" [isSeleted]="i==activeBonus"></div>
```

where variable are defined as below:

```
bonusJson = [{
    bonus:1500,
    amount:2000
  },{
    bonus:1000,
    amount:1000
  },{
    bonus:500,
    amount:500
  },{
    bonus:0,
    amount:100
  }];
  activeBonus = 0;
```

But view is not rendering correctly it is showing `undefind` in view as below.

$[image]

Comment: why is it a directive?

Comment: Sir, as it is a part of an assignment and asked so

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TL;DR

Don't use the value of `@Input()` properties inside the *constructor*. Use [`ngOninit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) instead.

---

### Long answer

You are executing your code in the **constructor**, but the **constructor** is executed before that the `Input`s are bound.

When you bootstrap your application, Angular will create a tree of components using the `new` keywoard for each of them and their constructor is thus executed. But in this phase *change detection* cycle isn't active yet, the tree hasn't still been attached to *DOM* and most of application data hasn't still been fetched and parsed.

The constructor isn't the ideal place to put complex initialization logic, as you can read in [this guide](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/), written by a developer of the Angular team. All what you will need to do in the constructor is just basic initialization and dependency injection result.

Things change in the `ngOnInit()` hook method. When Angular calls this method, instead, it has already attached each component to the DOM, injected all required dependencies and processed input bindings. You can safely use your `Input()` property with no fear.

---

#### Specific answer

Coming back to your question, you call `getTemplate()` it looks for `this.bonus`, `this.amount` and `this.isSelected` but the view of the parent component isn't still parsed and the input proprierites aren't still bound, so you receive `undefined` instead.

To avoid this problem, move your code from the **constructor** to the **ngOnInit** hook.

```
export class BonusCard implements OnInit {
  @Input() bonus: string;
  @Input() amount: string;
  @Input() isSeleted: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.getTemplate()
  }
```

---

#### Three final notes

I want to provide three additional advises to improve your code:

- *Use a DomSanitizer to bind HTML inside a component*, you can read more [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).
- *Use a template string*, you can use it substituting your quotes with backticks ( ` ), in this way you can write your template on several lines
- *you can use `===` instead of `==`*, if you are sure you are comparing two variables of the same type, like in this case.

So:

```
[isSeleted]="i===activeBonus"
```

and

```
return `<div>
          <div class="bonus"> ${this.bonus} </div>
          <div class="amount"> ${this.amount} </div>
          <div class="radio ${this.isSeleted?'is_seleted':''}"></div>
        </div>`;
```

Comment: That was a typo instead :) I fix it

Comment: you made my day